# How to take a specific color from a texture using ColorRamp

Tags: texturing, shaders, color, shader-nodes, color-management

So I have a nice dragon I'm working on, recently I thought it would be cool if I added a customization option to change the colors according to the texture using shaders.
I did it with the help of ColorRamp in Constant mode which is connected to a specific channel of the SepareteColor node (later I also used a driver that connects to color for this, but it is not related at the moment), so that I can take a certain range of colors and get it in black and white (that is, the selected areas are white and the rest are black ), then gives it to another ColorRamp in linear mode to change the color.
A picture of this:
[image]
However, because there is transition between colors in the texture, sometimes it gets the wrong colors in the wrong places, even though the color I need isn't there, like here:
[image]
This is where it's supposed to be, not at the connection points between parts: [image]
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Edit:
A little explanation about the nodes:

First, I have this basic setup of the texture:
[image]

Then, in the "DragonColoring"  group, I have those constant ColorRamps that gets the right position for the white slope by driver of the color and the right color channel from the Separate Color node, and the position of the black key by the driver of the white + 0.01 (it's changes between the ColorRamps):
[image]

Then, in the same group I have those color ramps that set the color to change the colors of the white areas I've got already from the previous ones, and put it on the output, and then connecting it to the Principled BSDF node:
[image]
[image]

Comment: If I click on your nodes screencap, I can't see the details and try to magnify only makes it blurry.  You may want to post a reduced version of your file in [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and copy/paste the HTML into your question.

Comment: My file weighs too much for that...

Comment: then an more detail picture/screen_cap of the nodes that I cannot see?  I don't see you getting any comments/help/solutions and want to just give you a tip on getting more, faster solutions.  it's hard to see that nodes you're using for alpha.  Is the mesh all one material, or so other materials get assigned to other vertices and/or their UV.

Comment: @james_t All right, thank you for helping me! i updated the question and added a clear explanation about the Nodes

Comment: Good update.  First question: if you look at the UVMap for your object in the "UV Editing", and the actual "MugWing Base Color" in "Texture Paint" workspace, is that all lining up properly?  You might check this by temporarily directly connecting "MugWing Base Color" image texture node to the Principled BSDF color input.  If that shows a problem, you'll need to either UV Unwrap again or Texture paint the image used by this shader node.

Comment: Everything looks good in the texture, what's next?